# Meaning of "has any installments pending till date"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Is it correct to write:

> 'The organization has any installments pending till date.'

Does the sentence convey the meaning that

> 'the organization does not have any installments pending as on date'?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

> 'The organization has any installments pending till date.'

makes no sense.

---

It should be either:

> 'The organization has **no** installments pending till date.'

Or:

> 'The organization **does not have** any installments pending till date.'